# use content from CDN on HTTPS pages

Tags: php, wordpress, https, cdn

I'm using a [W3 Total Cache](http://www.w3-edge.com/) with Amazon's CDN.
It works well through HTTP protocol, but in HTTPS page it makes links like -

```
https://cdn.mysite.com/img.gif
```

My question: how can I make link like that to become to be -

```
https://amazonaws.com/cdn.mysite.com/img.gif
```

(there is [a article](http://www.w3-edge.com/weblog/2011/11/how-to-w3tc-https-ssl/) about how disable the CDN or how to make the CDN's content non-ssl)